Is it possible to put regular methods on a FactoryBoy factory?
If I use the same logic in two lazy attributes, it would be nice to share that code.
A naive attempt to do this confuses FactoryBoy into thinking that the class method is a parameter for the factory (which is obviously fair enough!):
class SomeFactory(factory.Factory):

    def some_complex_logic(self, with_arg):
        ...

    @factory.lazy_attribute
    def foo(self):
        return self.some_complex_logic(with_arg="foo")

    @factory.lazy_attribute
    def bar(self):
        return self.some_complex_logic(with_arg="bar")

This gives you a message like:
AttributeError: The parameter 'some_complex_logic' is unknown. Evaluated attributes are {...}

Is there something I can decorate some_complex_logic with to tell FactoryBoy to ignore it? Is this maybe what exclude is for?

This is not formally documented, but FactoryBoy considers all attributes / methods as "declarations", except:

@classmethods and @staticmethods
Attributes and methods whose name starts with an _.

Thus, you could use:
class SomeFactory(factory.Factory):
  ...

  @classmethod
  def some_complex_logic(cls, x):
    ...

  foo = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda o: o.some_complex_logic(x=1))
  bar = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda o: o.some_complex_logic(x=2))


This is great. Actually the "starts with _" is more useful in this case because then I've got access to the instance. You can also decorate it with @property which you can't do in Python 3.12+.

I wonder why this isn't in the documentation. Seems pretty useful if it's officially allowed.

It actually seems like the underscore method works, but then that method isn't available within the lazy attribute. So it's not that useful...

My workaround is to make some_complex_logic a lazy_attribute and add it to exclude.
